# ¿Como hacer una consulta en dos tablas MYSQL y mostrar en tabla HTML?

Tags: mysql

Tengo estas dos tablas en MYSQL TABLA CLIENTE Y TABLA HISTORIAL, una que me almacena los datos de los clientes, y otra que me almacena los abonos que los clientes hacen de forma diaria, quisiera saber como hacer una consulta que me muestre los datos de los clientes en una tabla con toda la info, y en esa misma tabla que muestre otra columna que me salga si realizo un abono en la fecha del dia de hoy por ejemplo. pues ya la fecha seria una variable porque la validacion se haria diaria.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la tabla donde se guardan los datos de los clientes, y esta otra donde se guarda el historial
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que el resultado sea algo mas o menos de esta forma
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A tu segunda tabla le falta el id de la primera tabla, además yo pondría una tabla "clientes" y otra "prestamos" separadas. luego haces un left join, un where por fecha

Answer (score 0):

Para lograrlo tienes que utilizar un lenguaje de back-end te sugiero utilizar php y de php aprender lo que es el método post y el método get. Primeramente lo que tienes que hacer es crear la conexión a la base de datos, esta me ha servido por muchos años.

```
    $servidor="localhost";
    $usuario="root";
    $password= "";
    $db="erp";
    $connection = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $password, $db);
    if( $connection -> connect_errno ){
        echo("Problemas de conexi&#243;n con la base de datos");
        exit();
    }
    if(!$connection->set_charset("utf8")){
        printf("Error al cargar el conjunto de caracteres utf8:%s\n",
            $connection->error);
        exit ();
    }
    ?>
Este codigo es para que realices una busqueda

$query = "Select * from empleado where id_Empleado = '{$id}';";


$result = $connection->query($query);

if (!$result) {
    echo ("No se ha podido realizar la actualización de empleado !");
    exit();
}
$nrows = $result->num_rows;
 $connection->close();
Finalmente lo único que debes de hacer es ver como meter dentro un for lo que son las tablas de html, aquí te muestro un ejemplo solo adapatalo a tus necesidades

      
    echo "<center>";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<th>Producto</th>
    <th >Etiqueta</th>
    <th '>Precio</th>
    <th >Cantidad</th>
    <th >Impuestos (Iva 16%)</th>;
    <th >Subtotal</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < $nrows; $i++) {
        $result->data_seek($i);
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
      echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>", $row['nombre'], "</td>";
        echo "<td>", $row['etiqueta'], "</td>";
        echo "<td>", $row['costo'], "</td>";
        echo "<td>", $row['cantidad'], "</td>";
        echo "<td>", $row['impuestos'], "</td>";
        echo "<td>", $row['subtotal'], "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    $color = "#ff0000";
    echo "<tr  height='80'>
    <th colspan='6' >Total De registros : ", ($nrows),
    "</th></tr>";
    echo "<tr  height='80'>
    <th colspan='6' >Iva del 16% : ", ($impuestosTotal),
    "</th></tr>";
    echo "<tr  height='80'>
    <th colspan='6' >Total Factura: ", ( $totalTodo),
    "</th></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    
       ?>
```